# background to scroll with Scrollview

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, scrollview

how can i make the background scroll along the view or layout?

this is my layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/body_information">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="60dp"
    android:paddingEnd="60dp">



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a scrollView, you are causing the child (in this case, LinearLayout) to be moved across the screen and not by the ScrollView itself. So, to make the image move along with LinearLayout, place the background property on it.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/body_information"
android:paddingStart="60dp"
android:paddingEnd="60dp">
</LinearLayout>
```